# Real time tracking of words used in email in an entire organisation

Tags: email, exchange-server

1. Is it possible to track the frequency with which a certain word, or list of words (e.g. happy, sad, big, small) appears in an entire organization using Microsoft exchange server, in real time?
2. If it is possible, what's your best estimate of how much would it cost (including programming time, and any software that might be needed) to set it up and integrate it into an existing IT system, so that it can generate the reports for the frequency with which the words appear.